# Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf (Visual Studio Android Emulator)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.forms

I am developing Xamarin Cross platform application in which I am using Google Cloud Messaging service. So when I call below method, I get exception "Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf".
I trying to run this project on Visual Studio Android Emulator (MarshMallow Android 6.0 -API 23) and (Lollipop Android 5.1 - API 22)

So how to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
      try {
            GcmClient.CheckDevice(this);
            GcmClient.CheckManifest(this);

            // Register for push notifications
            Log.Info("MainActivity", "Registering...");
            GcmClient.Register(this, Constants.SenderID);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio Emulators do not have it installed by default. Hence you need to install the Gapps CyanogenMod, which contains the Google Apps needed to run things such as Push Notifications.

1. Download [Gapps CyanogenMod](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/) for your emulator version. (For the visual studio emulators you want to pick the HDPI / MDPI / TINY version).
2. Once downloaded make sure you have your emulator loaded. Drag and drop the zip file into the emulator. You will be prompted to install.

[image]

3. Press Install and Shutdown. It will then copy, extract and install the services.

[image]

4. Then start up your Visual Studio Emulator again. This might mean running your project again. However because it needs to configure a few things on boot your app might not start on the first emulator load. You may need to run your VS project again to run.

[image]

Now you will no longer get the `Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf` error.

Comment: If you have trouble with the dragging and dropping, make sure you're not running the emulator with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some of the Google provided emulator images do not have it, others do. I usually use a "Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)" image, if I use the Google provided emulator. For other emulators [this](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator) might work.